# Bolt Task Scheduler running at 11am instead of 3am

Tags: cron, bolt-cms

I've been monitoring the cron jobs I set up last week from my Bolt powered website. I've noticed that the daily cron jobs seem to be running at 11am (that's the time the database logs them at). In the config.yml the time is set to 3am.

I've checked the server time and that's using UTC. The MySQL database is using the server time so I would assume that to be UTC as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this on a Git master version, or 1.x?

Either way this definitely sounds like a bug.

**Edit:**
Was a bug and I have submitted a PR that fixes it for master and the version 1.6 branch.

However a possible workaround is to set the time of the existing records in the database so that the time of the last run is 03:00.

Comment: I'm using Bolt 1.6.10.

Comment: Ah, there was a bit of a rewrite of the logic for the upcoming version 2 of Bolt...  Which I just found a tiny bug in.

I have made some changes and set up a test environment, if that works I will push the backported changes to the 1.6 version for you.

Comment: I did try the database workaround by manually resetting the times but it still performed the jobs at 11am when I did it. I'll try your update anyway.

Comment: Hm... Weird.  The problem was one of time comparison, in that it only cared that (for example) the daily job was executed **after** the minimum hourly time — 03:00 in your case — but also it had to be at least 24 hours past the last run.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... so I thought changing to 3am would trick it. I can see that the weekly and monthly are still set to 3am because that time hasn't past yet.

Comment: Accepted. I'll keep an eye on it and let you know if it fails to update at 3am.

Comment: No stress mate, I did check mine too and that was also fine but somehow got lost in other work :-)